# How to install Magento Themes on google cloud VM?

Tags: magento

We bought a m]Magento theme for our store and we want to install it to our VM on google cloud, what shall we do? we can not find the hosting folder

please help

Thanks

Salah

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Web root is usually **/var/www**
And Magento's theme directory is **app/design/frontend//**

and finally you can activate your theme by going in the **Admin / System / Configuration / Design / Package** and themes and defined the name.

Let me know if you have any trouble.